# Idiomatic way to do ajax with json in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, json, ujs

[Codeschool's](http://www.codeschool.com) rails course gave the code below to do ajax with json (format.json). Why is the code so different from the way of doing ajax with unobtrusive javascript (format.js)?

Specifically I notice that the code below avoids UJS completely and does not use `remote: true` in the `form_for`. That is very different from the unobtrusive javascript approach which uses `remote: true` in the `form_for`.

Why is `remote: true` not suggested for ajax with json? I would have thought that ajax with json would use `remote: true` and have some way for the client javascript to register the `success` function to UJS so that the server's response is interpreted as json data by UJS and passed to the `success` function instead of UJS trying to execute as javascript as is done in the unobtrusive javascript approach.

Is there a better way of doing ajax with json than the below?

```
/views/zombies/show.html.erb

<div id="custom_phase2">
  <%= form_for @zombie, url: custom_decomp_zombie_path(@zombie) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :decomp %>
    <%= f.submit "Set" %>
  <% end %>
</div>


/app/assets/javascripts/zombies.js.coffee

$(document).ready ->
  $('div#custom_phase2 form').submit (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()

    url = $(this).attr('action')
    custom_decomp = $('div#custom_phase2 #zombie_decomp').val()

    $.ajax
      type: 'put'
      url: url
      data: { zombie: { decomp: custom_decomp } }
      dataType: 'json'
      success: (json) ->
        $('#decomp').text(json.decomp).effect('highlight')
        $('div#custom_phase2').fadeOut() if json.decomp == "Dead (again)"
```

Comment: Consider using AngularJS, EmberJS, or another well-used framework such as those listed and demostrated here: http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/ It's fine to learn how to do in JQuery, but then take advantage of what is already written.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **remote_form_for** helper:

```
/views/zombies/show.html.erb

<div id="custom_phase2">
  <%= remote_form_for @zombie, url: custom_decomp_zombie_path(@zombie), :update => {:success => "form", :failure => "errors"} do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :decomp %>
    <%= f.submit "Set" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Here "form" is the id of the element that will be update on sucess and "errors" the id of the element that will be updated if there is as error.

References: [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ajax_on_rails.html) and [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/remote_form_for)